# How to retrieve contents from Map<String, Map<String,String>>?

Tags: java

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> regMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
```

How do I retrieve contents from `regMap`? Is there any data structure where I can store three related things ?

Comment: You'll have to explain much more detail what the problem is if you want to get useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...or is there any data structure where i can store three related things?

Just create your own class.

```
public class Foo {

  private final Bar thingOne;
  private final Bar thingTwo;
  private final Bar thingThree;

  // ...

}
```

You can then store this in a `Collection` if necessary.

*Note: don't take my trivial example as a suggestion you should name your fields `foo1`, `foo2` etc. Give them meaningful names, such as `forename`, `surname`, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are **sure** `"firstKey"` exists in `regMap`, use:

```
String value = regMap.get("firstKey").get("secondKey");
```

Or else:

```
private String safelyGetString(String firstKey, String secondKey) {
    Map<String,String> temp = regMap.get(firstKey);
    return (temp == null ? null : temp.get(secondKey));
}
```

Comment: A NullPointerException will be throw if regMap.get("firstKey") returns null

Comment: That's why I've added: "If you are sure "firstKey" exists in regMap..."

Answer (score 0):

One way could be

```
Map<String,String> innerMap= regMap.get("string");
String value=null;
if(innerMap!=null)
 value=innerMap.get("insidemap");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure that the key to the first map is valid, you can use

```
String value = regMap.get("key1").get("key2");
```

This will, however, throw a NullPointerException when the key isn't found in the first map. To check for this, do this:

```
String value;
Map<String, String> subMap = regMap.get("key1");
if (subMap != null) {
    value = subMap.get("key2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to use such a structure. As written before, it is better to use your own Objects in a Map, so you can access them better than a Map in a Map.